# Retrieving the a column value where the primary key is a tuple (a,b) and where all rows (a,b') must exist for a given list for b' values

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, count, psycopg2

I have a table of form A|B|C where a tuple (a,b) *in* (A,B) is the primary key. I have list of values (BVALs) for B and I require the elements in the column A where a row entry for each value of the type (a,b') for b' *in* BVALs exists.

Currently I have implemented a script that retrieves the first all (a,b'') for the first element of the BVALs, which then iterates and refines the list until the last element of the BVALs. I believe it will be slow in big databases and believe that an faster solution exists. Would appreciate any help.

Let's say we have the following table:

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
+---+---+
```

If the BVALs list consists of (1,2) then the query should return 1 and 2

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your explanation is rather hard to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want `a`s that have all `b` values. If so, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select a
from mytable
where b in (1, 2)   -- either value
group by a
having count(*) = 2 -- both match
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select distinct a
from t
where b in ( . .  . );  -- list of b values here
```